# Compare two arrays (users, contactInfo) based on first and last name

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, compare

How to compare two arrays, lets say *users* array consists of 2 objects of the same last name and *contactInfo* array for them have only one object with same last name. In my code for this case, users is picking the wrong contact info.

Below are the main idea of the required task:

Compare *users* arrays with *contactInfo* array and push the contact if the both last name or first name matches.

1. Compare with last name, if their is no duplicates(*users*/contactInfo with same last name).
2. Compare with first name:
   If their is some users who have the same last name then check with first name instead.

Code:

```
    let users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Leanne",
    "last_name": "Graham",
    "username": "Leanne.Graham"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Ervin",
    "last_name": "Howell",
    "username": "Ervin.Howell"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Clementine",
    "last_name": "Bauch",
    "username": "Clementine.Bauch"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Patricia",
    "last_name": "Howell",
    "username": "Patricia.Howell"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Patricia",
    "last_name": "Lebsack",
    "username": "Patricia.Lebsack"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "first_name": "Chelsey",
    "last_name": "Dietrich",
    "username": "Chelsey.Dietrich"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "first_name": "Dennis",
    "last_name": "Schulist",
    "username": "Dennis.Schulist"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "first_name": "Kurtis",
    "last_name": "Weissnat",
    "username": "Kurtis.Weissnat"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "first_name": "Nicholas",
    "last_name": "Runolfsdottir",
    "username": "Nicholas.Runolfsdottir"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "first_name": "Glenna",
    "last_name": "Reichert",
    "username": "Glenna.Reichert"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "first_name": "Clementina",
    "last_name": "DuBuque",
    "username": "Clementina.DuBuque"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "first_name": "Dani",
    "last_name": "Reichert",
    "username": "Dani.Reichert"
  },
];

let contactInfo = [
  {
    "first_name": "Leanne",
    "last_name": "Graham",
    "email": "Leanne@Graham.biz",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "LeanneGraham.org"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Ervin",
    "last_name": "Howell",
    "email": "Ervin@Howell.tv",
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "ErvinHowell.net"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Clementine",
    "last_name": "Bauch",
    "email": "Clementine@Bauch.net",
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ClementineBauch.info",
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Patricia",
    "last_name": "Lebsack",
    "email": "Patricia@Lebsack.org",
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "PatriciaLebsack.biz"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Chelsey",
    "last_name": "Dietrich",
    "email": "Chelsey@Dietrich.ca",
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "ChelseyDietrich.info"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Dennis",
    "last_name": "Schulist",
    "email": "Dennis@Schulist.info",
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "DennisSchulist.org"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Kurtis",
    "last_name": "Weissnat",
    "email": "Kurtis@Weissnat.biz",
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "KurtisWeissnat.io"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Nicholas",
    "last_name": "Runolfsdottir",
    "email": "Nicholas@Runolfsdottir.me",
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "NicholasRunolfsdottir.com",
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Glenna",
    "last_name": "Reichert",
    "email": "Glenna@Reichert.io",
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "GlennaReichert.com"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Dani",
    "last_name": "Reichert",
    "email": "Dani@Reichert.io",
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "DaniReichert.com"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Clementina",
    "last_name": "DuBuque",
    "email": "Clementina@DuBuque.biz",
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ClementinaDuBuque.net"
  }
];

let usersArray = [];

for(let el of users) {
    let obj1 = [];
    
    for(let val of contactInfo) {
        if(el.last_name == val.last_name) {
            obj1.push(val);
        }    
    }
    
    if(obj1.length > 1) {
        let contactDup = obj1;
        for(let val of contactDup) {
            if(el.first_name == val.first_name) {
                let contact = val;
                let obj = Object.assign(el, contact);
                usersArray.push(obj);
            }
        }
    } else {
        let contact = obj1[0];
        let obj = Object.assign(el, contact);
        usersArray.push(obj);
    }
}

console.log('usersArray', usersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Abdur, the problem is that ***obj1*** maintains an array based on the **last name**. When the loop hits 'Howell' for 'Patricia', the code will keep 'Ervin Howell' for **val**, because 'Ervin' comes first in the loop. Thus ***contact*** at this point is 'Ervin' and ***el*** is 'Patricia'. So we have 2 objects that share the same last name, but are different when we try the Object.assign(el, contact) approach.

I've tried this approach which simplifies checking for duplicate entries using validation that compares user.username with the string concatenation of contactInfo.first_name and contactInfo.last_name and checks if the username is already in usersArray .

```
let usersArray = [];

for (let user of users) {

  for (let contact of contactInfo) {
    let contactInfoUserName = `${contact.first_name}.${contact.last_name}`.toLowerCase();

    if ((user.username.toLowerCase() === contactInfoUserName) && !usersArray.some(user => user.username.toLowerCase() === contactInfoUserName)) {
      usersArray.push(Object.assign(user, contact));
    }
  }
}
console.log('usersArray', usersArray);
```

Comment: No, as task requirement I can just match with last name and first name (in case of duplicates).